# Limit a function to firing once before being reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following functions which monitor for scroll positions and trigger functions (within Iscroll4).

The bgFadeToggle() function basically triggers a function to show/hide a menu.  It contains a variable which stores up/down state so that the same function is only triggered once during the scroll.

The problem I have is that if a users scrolls up and down reasonably quickly the functions continuously trigger - which causes a comedy a dancing effect on the screen!  Can anyone recommend a way that repeated calls would be ignored within a certain timeframe to avoid this problem?

```
 onScrollMove: function() {
           var thisScrol =  myScroll.getScrollY()
           if (thisScrol < -80 ){
                bgfadeToggle('on');
            }
            if (thisScrol > -80){
               bgfadeToggle('off');
            }
},
```

bfFadeToggle code -

```
    function bgfadeToggle(which){
if (which == "on" && first == "yes"){
    //alert('on yes') ;alert(first)
    setTimeout(function() {first="no";$('#wrapper').addClass('hov');  }, 10)

                $('.appearLate').fadeIn('500');

                $('.footer').animate({
                    bottom: [ "-40", "swing" ],
                    opacity: "0"
                  }, 100, "linear");


                $( ".appearLate" ).animate({
                    top: [ "30", "swing" ],
                    opacity: "1"
                  }, 1000, "linear");

}

if (which == "off" && first== "no"){
    //alert('off no') ;alert(first)
    setTimeout(function() {first="yes";$('#wrapper').removeClass('hov'); }, 10)

            $( ".appearLate" ).animate({
                    top: [ "-55", "swing" ],

                  }, 1300, "linear");

            $('.footer').animate({
                    bottom: [ "0", "swing" ],
                    opacity: "1"
                  }, 1000, "linear");

}

}
```

Comment: How do you show your menu ? Can you show `bgfadeToggle` code ?

Comment: just added - cheers Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a boolean value `animationDone`.

Set it to false before animation, then true. And don't do other animations while the boolean is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put a lock around your function calls, the lock should be a global variable and declared as false:

```
onScrollMove: function() {
       var thisScrol =  myScroll.getScrollY()
       if (thisScrol < -80 && !locked){
            locked = true;
            bgfadeToggle('on');
            locked = false;
        }
        if (thisScrol > -80 && !locked){
           locked = true;
           bgfadeToggle('off');
           locked = false;
        }
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You can use a late-invoke pattern like this:

```
onScrollMove: function () {
    var thisScrol = myScroll.getScrollY();
    scrollCallback.invoke(thisScrol < -80);
};

var scrollCallback = function () {
    var _timeoutId,
        _delayToCall = 500;
    return {
        invoke: function (lessThan) {
            window.clearTimeout(_timeoutId);
            _timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
                bgfadeToggle(lessThan ? 'on' : 'off');
            }, _delayToCall);
        }
    };
}();
```